# count users within a given age range - ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, charts, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to have a function to group users according to a certain age range. Then get their count which I can use to plot a bar-chart.
e

this statement is able to plot a chart of their ages, but it is each users age. which is what i want to eliminate. if you would like to know  am using [chartkick](http://chartkick.com/) to make the charts.

```
<%= bar_chart User.group("date_trunc('year', age(dob))").count, {library: {title: "User's Age"}} %>
```

I want the ages returned as:

```
<%= bar_chart [["Below 10", users_with_ages_lying_in this_range.count],
          ["10-19", users_with_ages_lying_in this_range.count],
          ["20-29", ],
          ["30-39", ],
          ["40-49", ],
          ["above 50",]], {library: {title: "User's Age"}} 
%>
```

in short I would like this line of code `User.group("date_trunc('year', age(dob))").count` to return only users for a given age range.

If you have any better ideas I would appreciate to know.
*I'm using postgres DB*

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need to find events within a range.

I made a class method on a model:

```
  def self.in_range(start_range, end_range)
    where "((start_date <= ?) and (end_date >= ?))", end_range, start_range
  end
```

which is used like so:

```
events.in_range(start_range, end_range).order('start_date ASC')
```

I am sure a similar one could be created using age instead of start_date and end_date.